# Maven Archetype creation via Eclipse

Tags: maven, architecture, maven-archetype, archetypes

I am willing to create an archetype which will be useful to create a lot of projects sharing the same architecture. I followed the maven guide and read some bloggers guides but even with these informations I am struggling.

I have some constraints for my projects :

- All the project code is in a package which must be something like com.ei.**app**.**project** (**app** and **project** are vars I would like to set during the project generation)
- I have dependencies I would like to be present in my POM when the project is generated
- I have some scripts file with data (paths, app name...) and I would like to set them according to the project parameters, and if it is possible add additional parameters.
- We don't use the official maven repo but set up another online repo. We have a strict security policy an whenever we have to add a lib into the repo it takes a lot of time for verifications.

How can I achieve this ? I tried several solutions but encountered a lot of errors. If you have a complete step-by-step guide in english or french that would be fantastic, but I would also like to understand how it works.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer parts of your question.

From an example project, you can create an archetype by using `archetype:create-from-project` (https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html).

You can supply a property file that will be used to replace actual values (like `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`) with references (like `$version`). All filtered files will be treated as velocity templates so that you can use $-type replacement.

Your repository restriction may be problem because you probably need dozens of artifacts to make the archetype plugin run.

Comment: Yep, I think my company filters some of the needed artifacts. I made a ticket to add those I need but I needed a fast solution so I found another way. Anyway, many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I finally created a "base" project with all I need inside (libraries, main Vert.x class...), and developed a script to replace a template value (i.e `__projectName__` ) in dir / file names and inside configuration / pom.

It's close enough to what we need and provide a cool replacement tool for my company, which will be used for multiple purposes.

Comment: Be careful with reinventing the wheel. All these scripts come haunting you in three years when nobody understands them anymore. It is also easy to forget special cases.

Comment: The script is very simple, and will be documented. We will for sure come to the archetype solution when the conditions are reunited, but for the moment we needed a fast solution